# Problem with a variable

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a simple `if/else` statement to show a next or previous link, but somehow my checkup don't work. Here's the code

```
var newPosition = currPosition;
$(".imageNavLink").click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 newPosition = (this.rel == "next") ? newPosition + 1 : newPosition - 1;
 var newImageLink = this.title;
 var clickAction = this.rel;
 var newImage = new Image();
 $(newImage).load(function(){
  newWidth = this.width, newHeight = this.height+35;
  if(newPosition == totalItems){
   [.. Show 'previous' link ..]
  }else if(newPosition == 1){
   [.. Show 'next' link ..]
  }else{
   [.. Show 'previous' and 'next' link ..]
  }
 });
 newImage.src = this.title;
});
```

- `currPosition` holds the current position (numeric) of the element to keep on track with the count
- `totalItems` is the numeric value of the total associated images

If i click on the first image i constantly see the previous link, when i start with the second image i constantly see both links and when i start with the last image i constantly see the previous link..

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is it but,

```
newWidth = this.width, newHeight = this.height+35;
```

Shouldn't the `,` after `this.width` be a `;` ?

Comment: Not the problem indeed. Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(newPosition == totalItems){
   [.. Show 'previous' link ..]
  }else if(newPosition == 1){
   [.. Show 'next' link ..]
  }else{
   [.. Show 'previous' and 'next' link ..]
  }
```

rewrite to this:

```
 if(newPosition>1 && newPosition<totalItems){
   [.. Show 'previous' and 'next' link ..]
  }else if(newPosition == 1){
   [.. Show 'next' link ..]
  }else if(newPosition == totalItems){
   [.. Show 'previous' link..]
  }
```

Only if `newPosition` is between `1` and `totalItems` will both `prev` and `next` be shown

Comment: I'm starting to think that the problem is somewhere else, because if i now click the first image i don't see anything. When i click the second i only get the previous link and also if i click the last image i see the previous button... The problem is that there is no relative (at least i think) around it..

Comment: is the value `totalImages` changing everytime you click an item?

Comment: Nope. It is defined above and stays the same everytime.. I check everything with an <code>alert(currPosition+" -> "+newPosition+" -> "+totalItems);</code> and everything seems to change well there... newPosition is the only one that changes..